# Disable SSL on Websphere Application Server

Tags: ssl, websphere

Is there a way to disable SSL on WAS? So you can just log on using a username and password. That isnt tied to disabling the Global Security?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the login part of the application has nothing to do with the protocol you use to reach your application, e.g. you can use a login dialog (forms, http auth... etc), with 'normal' http or http over SSL (SSL being preferred if the app is not inhouse use only, even if it is, I would think about using SSL).

In WebSphere you deploy your application on a [Virtual Host](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/ccws_vhost.html?resultof=%22%76%69%72%74%75%61%6c%22%20%22%68%6f%73%74%22%20). A virtual host is a collection of host names and ports (called host aliases) from which your application should be reachable. So to get the behaviour you want, I would create a new virtual host (description is for the WebSphere Admin Console Application in 6.1):

```
Environment > Virtual Host > New
```

Give it a descriptive name, like http_only. Afterwards you do:

```
Environment > Virtual Host > http_only > Host Aliases > New
```

There you add a host name or a asterisk ('*', without the quotes) and a port number (in this case the port for http. Next is changing the virtual host your application is bound on:

```
Applications > Enterprise Applications > app_name > Virtual hosts
```

There are dropdown boxes you can choose the virtual hosts from. After that and a save, the app should be reacheable only over http.